# Eliminate rows that have a match in one of multiple columns of the preceding rows

Tags: r

I have a large data.frame. Here a simpler version for more clarity.

```
ID <- rep(c(1,2,3),each=4)
Bed <- rep(c(1,1,2,2),3)
ERRBeg <- c(90,140,190,200,290,340,390,100,490,540,560,610)
POST1Beg <- c(100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600,650)
POST2Beg <- c(110,160,210,260,310,360,410,460,510,560,610,660)
DATA <- data.frame(ID,Bed,ERRBeg,POST1Beg,POST2Beg)
```

It looks like that:

I want to delete all rows that have the following match:
The value of ERRBeg is found in POST1Beg or POST2Beg (i have more variables) in one of the previous rows (only if ID and Bed is the same)

```
      ID   Bed ERRBeg POST1Beg POST2Beg LAG_ERRBeg LAG_POST1Beg
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     1     1     90      100      110         NA           NA
 2     1     1    140      150      160         90          100
 3     1     2    190      200      210         NA           NA
 4     1     2    200      250      260        190          200
 5     2     1    290      300      310         NA           NA
 6     2     1    340      350      360        290          300
 7     2     2    390      400      410         NA           NA
 8     2     2    100      450      460        390          400
 9     3     1    490      500      510         NA           NA
10     3     1    540      550      560        490          500
11     3     2    560      600      610         NA           NA
12     3     2    610      650      660        560          600
```

I tried this which gives me the exact line where two variables match. However if i turn it around using `filter(!ERRBeg == lag(POST1Beg))` it deletes all line where ID and Bed has duplicates.

```
DATA %>%
  group_by(ID, Bed)%>%
  filter(ERRBeg == lag(POST1Beg) ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I also tried this which does not work. I know i might be missing something trivial, but i do not see it.

```
DATA_xx <- DATA %>%
  group_by(ID, Bed)%>%
  filter(ERRBeg %in% c(lag(ERRBeg),lag(POST1Beg)) ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Desired Output:

```
      ID   Bed ERRBeg POST1Beg POST2Beg LAG_ERRBeg LAG_POST1Beg
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     1     1     90      100      110         NA           NA
 2     1     1    140      150      160         90          100
 3     1     2    190      200      210         NA           NA
 5     2     1    290      300      310         NA           NA
 6     2     1    340      350      360        290          300
 7     2     2    390      400      410         NA           NA
 8     2     2    100      450      460        390          400
 9     3     1    490      500      510         NA           NA
10     3     1    540      550      560        490          500
11     3     2    560      600      610         NA           NA
```

Comment: Can you show what the result should look like?

Comment: Eliminating line 4 (ERRBeg==Lag POST1Beg) and line 12 (ERRBeg==Lag POST2Beg).

Answer (score 1):

```
DATA %>%
group_by(ID, Bed)%>%
filter(!ERRBeg %in% POST1Beg ) %>%
ungroup()
```

I tried this of switching the lag to be an in, and it works I think
Edit: Will not work forward i.e if ERRBeg value appears in a POST1Beg later in the values.
  Putting lag back around the post will fix this I believe

```
 DATA %>%
 group_by(ID, Bed)%>%
 filter(!ERRBeg %in% lag(POST1Beg) ) %>%
 ungroup()
```

Comment: I see. The problem starts when putting the same variable in the lag. This works: c(lag(POST1Beg),lag(POST2Beg)), but this does not c(lag(ERRBeg),lag(POST1Beg),lag(POST2Beg)). Any ideas why? And how to work around?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem and the solution. :)

```
DATA %>%
  group_by(ID, Bed)%>%
  filter(!ERRBeg %in% c(lag(ERRBeg),lag(POST1Beg),lag(POST2Beg)) | is.na(lag(ERRBeg))  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The problem was that i do not only get TRUE, FALSE, but also NA as a result of the equation in the filter.

```
      ID   Bed ERRBeg POST1Beg POST2Beg FILTER
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl> 
 1     1     1     90      100      110 NA    
 2     1     1    140      150      160 FALSE 
 3     1     2    190      200      210 NA    
 4     2     1    290      300      310 NA    
 5     2     1    340      350      360 FALSE 
 6     2     2    390      400      410 NA    
 7     2     2    100      450      460 FALSE 
 8     3     1    490      500      510 NA    
 9     3     1    540      550      560 FALSE 
10     3     2    560      600      610 NA
```